# SQL Developer Restore Tabs

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I prevent SQL Developer from restoring tabs when it starts up? It seems to open with every query I have ever saved. Is there a way to control which are restored?

Comment: I am looking for a way TO DO that :D

Comment: I am STILL looking for a way to do that 